# Calendar overlay colors not shown in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar, outlook

I created a Sharepoint calendar with several colored overlays.  I click the Connect to Outlook button and the calendar is shown in Microsoft Outlook.  The colors are not shown.  Everything is a uniform color.  Is there any way to show the colors in Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured it out.  You can use Conditional formatting to set the color of the event.  You will need to make sure that for example the subject contains a certain text that you can search for.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, the overlays are just useful ways to group data visually.  It all exists in one calendar in SharePoint and therefore it all gets pulled in as one calendar into Outlook.  Outlook calendar overlays are different calendars entirely layered on top of each other.

Comment: was afraid of that :I